# How to read a file containing c-struct in nodeJS?

Tags: c, node.js, struct

In NodeJS, I have to parse a binary file written in C, composed of binary c-struct.

This is the c-code I have to convert in NodeJS.

```c
  typedef struct INPUTPARM {                                     
    ushort inputFlag;                                    
    char inputName[20];
  }

  // ...
  FILE *fInp = NULL; 
  struct INPUTPARM inputParm;

  fInp = fopen(filePath, "rb");

  // in a loop, it reads one record every time

  fread ((void *)&inputParm, 1, sizeof(struct INPUTPARM), fInp);
```

How to code the same in NodeJS?

Comment: There are [libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-struct) that do this, but please don't. This is not a good idea for a number of reason, not last of all the fact that by doing this it you make your dataset not portable, not only to a different architecture (of course, hi there [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) for example) but also to different compilers. Structure packing and padding is complicated, I advise you to use a different method for saving your data.

Comment: I'm not the owner of the c application. That file is generated by a legacy c application and I need to parse that in node.js. BTW, I used the library you suggested, and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved in this way, using [c-struct](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-struct) module:

```
var fileData = Buffer.from(binaryFileData, 'binary');
var _ = require('c-struct');
var inputParam = new _.Schema({
  inputFlag: _.type.uint16,  // ushort
  inputName: _.type.string() // string is 0-terminated
});
// register to cache
_.register('InputParam', inputParam);

var out = [];
for (var i = 0; i < fileData.length; i+=22) {
  var partial = fileData.slice(i, i+22);
  out.push(_.unpackSync('InputParam', partial));
}
console.log(out);
```